# Optimizar Base de datos Mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

tengo una TABLA  llamada "Datos" la cual lleno con información traída desde un archivo CSV(Generada desde un sistema de terceros).

la base de datos tiene múltiples columna con Códigos que no son numéricos.
Este es solo un ejemplo pequeño[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la tabla Datos Fácilmente supero los **250,000** registros por mes

como "**Solución**" yo había pensado en dividir la tabla datos en varias tablas. es decir **clientes , rutas , produtos**

y llenar  dichas tablas desde consultas mysql tales como

```
insert into productos(producto_codigo,producto)
select producto_codigo,producto from datos
```

esto agregando también un id auto numérico a cada tabla para lograr un resultado como este
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego de esto insertar la llave auto numérica en la tabla de "Datos" con la siguiente consulta

```
UPDATE datos as d,productos as p
SET d.productoid = p.id
where d.codigo_producto = p.codigo_producto
```

lo cual funciono durante un tiempo. con el tiempo los querys tardaban mas y mas . obviamente estoy haciéndolo mal

**para ustedes cual seria la manera correcta de hacerlo ?**
**como hago que esto sea óptimo?**

teniendo en cuenta que el archivo CSV es la única forma posible de migrar datos debido a problemas de negocios con la empresa de terceros

Comment: Buen día; agrega índices (index) por cada campo que uses para búsqueda agiliza las consultas; desde luego también toma en cuenta que el volumen de información puede afectar el desempeño de MySQL, por tanto deseabnle este en una compu solo el manejador de Bd.

Comment: estas usando indices? aparte de los pk tambien deberias tener indice para codigo_producto que es quien une las tablas en tu update

Comment: El archivo `.csv` como muestras la imagen tiene forma de ser varias tablas no una minimamente yo separaria el contenido en 2 tablas  `productos` y `clientes` ahora bien como te dijo la mayoría agregar indices sobre los campos que consulta es un comienzo, tambien podrias reducir el tamaño de los campos varchar o char de la tabla ¿como la definiste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambios que deberías realizar:

- Primero, crear indices para `productos.codigo_producto` y `datos.codigo_producto`.

  Ejemplo:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE `productos` ADD INDEX (`codigo_producto`(24));
  ALTER TABLE `datos` ADD INDEX (`codigo_producto`(24));

  # Donde "(24)" es la cantidad de caracteres que serán tomados para crear los indices
  # Modifica dicho valor a gusto
  ```
- Una vez que hayas creados estos indices puedes optimizar la consulta del `UPDATE` así:

  ```
  UPDATE datos as d
    INNER JOIN productos as p
      ON p.codigo_producto = d.codigo_producto
  SET d.productoid = p.id
  ```